# Trying to get property 'id' of non-object (View:

Tags: php, laravel

I get an error when I try to edit.
My project working to a website which will have the function of radio stations and I'm having this problem that I can't identify where the error is In this case, that's what's going around and I can't solve it.

> Trying to get property 'id' of non-object (View:
> C:\xampp\htdocs\radio\resources/views/ContactUs/list.blade.php)

```
@section('content')
<div class="app-content my-3 my-md-5">
    <div class="side-app">
        <div class="page-header">
            <h4 class="page-title">All Contact Us</h4>
            <div>
                <a href="{{ url('/admin/contact_us/'.$contact->id.'/edit')}}" class="btn btn-pill btn-primary">Edit Contact Us</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="featured_banner">

        </div> 
        @if(session()->has('success'))
        <div class="alert alert-success  alert-dismissible">
            <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
            <strong>Success!</strong> {{session('success')}}
        </div>
        @elseif(session()->has('error'))
        <div class="alert alert-danger  alert-dismissible">
            <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
            <strong>Danger!</strong> {{session('error')}}
        </div>
        @endif
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <h3 class="card-title"></h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="siteInformation table-responsive">
                        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th><h6>Field</h6></th>
                                    <th><h6>Value</h6></th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr><td>Phone No</td><td>{{$contact->phone_no}}</td></tr>
                                <tr><td>Email</td><td>{{$contact->email}}</td></tr>
                                <tr><td>Address</td><td>{{$contact->address}}</td></tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <div class="paginate-div">
                    </div>
                    <!-- table-responsive -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

this is department controller.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\ContactUs;
use DB;
use DataTables;

class ContactUsController extends Controller
{

  public function __construct(){
    $this->middleware('auth');
    $this->middleware('checkadmin');
    view()->share('active', 'settings');
  }



    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
     
     $contact = ContactUs::first();
     return view('ContactUs.list' , compact('contact'));

   }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
      return view('ContactUs.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
      $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'phone_no' => 'required',
        'email'=>'required|email',
        'address'=>'required|min:5|max:80'
      ]);
      if($validatedData){
        $data = $request->all();
        $contact = new ContactUs;
        if($contact->create($data)){
          $request->session()->flash('success', 'Contact created successfully.');
          return redirect()->route('contact_us.index');
        }
        else{
          $request->session()->flash('error', 'Something went wrong.');
          return back()->withInput();
        }
      }
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {

    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
      $contact = ContactUs::find($id);
      return view('ContactUs.edit',compact('id','contact'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
      $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'phone_no' => 'required',
        'email'=>'required|email',
        'address'=>'required|min:5|max:80'
      ]);
      if($validatedData){
        $data = $request->all();
        $contact = ContactUs::find($id);
        if($contact->update($data)){
          $request->session()->flash('success', 'Contact updated successfully.');
          return redirect()->route('contact_us.index');
        }
        else{
          $request->session()->flash('error', 'Something went wrong.');
          return back()->withInput();
        }
      }
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
      $contact = ContactUs::find($id);
      $contact->delete();
      return redirect('admin/contact_us')
      ->with('success','Contact Us deleted successfully');
    }
  }
```

some help here because I can't solve it because I'm also new to Laravel

Comment: I bet this line `$contact = ContactUs::first();` return null, you have to check if there's a contact or not

Comment: Yes resolved, thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are no ContactUs records in your database, then `$contact` will be null, and you'll get the error you're getting.

You need to ensure you have a valid `$contact` object before trying to access its 'id.' You can use an if statement to check if `$contact` exists and then conditionally render the edit link, like the following.

```
@if ($contact)
    <a href="{{ url('/admin/contact_us/'.$contact->id.'/edit')}}" class="btn btn-pill btn-primary">Edit Contact Us</a>
@endif
```